# JQuery property selector with Wildcard

Tags: jquery, gridview, wildcard, handle

I am trying to shift the Row index after clicking my Up/Down arrows inside a gridview, Unfortunately when I enter my Jquery it only seems to be getting a handle on 1 of the gridviews inside my Repeater.

The ID I am passing to get a handle on the row is:

```
$('#Repeater1_ctl16_MeetingSumaryGridview1 a.move').click(function () {
```

The problem is that the ***'ctl16'*** changes depending on which gridview I have selected the arrows from, I would like to be able to put a wildcard in here that will get a handle on the gridview for the Arrows I have selected.

Below is my JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#Repeater1_ctl16_MeetingSumaryGridview1 a.move').click(function () {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      if ($(this).hasClass('up')) {
          var headrChck = row.prev()
          if (headrChck[0].cells['1'].tagName != 'TH') {
              row.prev().before(row);
          }
      }
      else {
          row.next().after(row);
      }
  });
})
```

I have tried many things that I have found online but all the Wildcards i seem to use do not get a handle.

I was wondering if I could get some Help/Advice on this, Anything is appreciated, Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you will find that `^` and `$` are wildcards in jQuery.

I think in your case it should look something like this:

```
$("[id^=Repeater1]").click(function () {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      if ($(this).hasClass('up')) {
          var headrChck = row.prev()
          if (headrChck[0].cells['1'].tagName != 'TH') {
              row.prev().before(row);
          }
      }
      else {
          row.next().after(row);
      }
  });
```

---

**TL;DR;**

- use `*` for `contains`
- use `^` for `starts with`
- use `$` for `end with`

Beware that the comparison is case sensitive.